# Parse text from a .txt file using csv module

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, csv

I have an email that comes in everyday and the format of the email is always the same except some of the data is different. I wrote a VBA Macro that exports the email to a text file. Now that it is a text file I want to parse the data so that I get only the new information.

The format of email is like this

```
> Irrelevant data  
> Irrelevant data
> Type:     YUK
> Status:   OPEN
> Date:     6/22/2015
> Description: ----
> 
> Description blah blah blah
> Thank you
```

I want to capture the relevant data. For example, in this case i would like to only capture YUK, OPEN, 6/22/2015 and the Description blah blah blah. I tried using the csv module to go line by line and print out the lines but i cant seem to find a way to parse that information.

This is what I have so far. it only prints out the lines though.

```
import os
import glob
import csv

path = "emailtxt/"
glob = max(glob.iglob(path + '*.txt'), key=os.path.getctime)#most recent file located in the emailtxt
newestFile = os.path.basename(glob)#removes the emailtxt\ from its name

f = open(path+newestFile)

read = csv.reader(f)
for row in read:
    print row

f.close()
```

How would I parse through the text file?

Comment: is your file in `csv` format to go for `csv` module?

Comment: Are you trying to parse a non-CSV file (an email) with a CSV parser? That's not going to work; you need to write your own parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Regular Expression

```
def get_info(string_to_search):
    res_dict = {}
    import re

    find_type = re.compile("Type:[\s]*[\w]*")
    res = find_type.search(string_to_search)
    res_dict["Type"] = res.group(0).split(":")[1].strip()

    find_Status = re.compile("Status:[\s]*[\w]*")
    res = find_Status.search(string_to_search)
    res_dict["Status"] = res.group(0).split(":")[1].strip()

    find_date = re.compile("Date:[\s]*[/0-9]*")
    res = find_date.search(string_to_search)
    res_dict["Date"] = res.group(0).split(":")[1].strip()

    res_dict["description"] = string_to_search.split("Description:")[1].replace("Thank you","")
    return res_dict


search_string = """> Irrelevant data
> Irrelevant data
> Type:     YUK
> Status:   OPEN
> Date:     6/22/2015
> Description: ----
>
> Description blah blah blah
> Thank you
"""
info =  get_info(search_string)

print info
print info["Type"]
print info["Status"]
print info["Date"]
print info["description"]
```

Output :

```
{'Status': 'OPEN', 'Date': '6/22/2015', 'Type': 'YUK', 'description': ' ----\n>\n> Description blah blah blah\n> \n'}
YUK
OPEN
6/22/2015
 ----
>
> Description blah blah blah
>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't thin here you are in need of `csv` module at all, just regular File I/O will do for you what you want, i.e; read the file line by line and from each line extract the data you need and store it in a `list` for example:

```
import os
import glob

path = "emailtxt/"
glob = max(glob.iglob(path + '*.txt'), key=os.path.getctime)#most recent file located in the emailtxt
newestFile = os.path.basename(glob)          #removes the emailtxt\ from its name

capture_list = []                            #list to hold captured words
with open(path+newestFile, 'r') as f:        #open the file for reading
    for line in f:                           #Go line by line
        capture_list.append(line.split()[2]) #add to the list last word
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to print out the rows individually, parsing them is a matter of breaking apart the rows (that are represented as strings). Assuming there is some space after each item descriptor, or a colon after each descriptor, you could use that to parse whatever comes after that colon and space. see the python string [common operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) to be able to split the row at useful points.

In terms of actually parsing the data, You could do a series of if statements to catch each status, or file type. for the date, try the [time.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) function to evaluate the date to a datetime object. All you have to do is match the format of the date, which in your case seems to be "%m/%d/%y".

Comment: Thanks Guys, That seems to have done it. I will go ahead and learn more about it. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there the `cvs` module is the one to be used here. If you are just going for a simple search, use string comparisons and split them by characteristic characters. If it's more sophisticated, go for regular expressions.

```
import os

with open("email.txt") as file:
    data = [line.replace("> ","") for line in file.readlines()]
    for line in data:
        s = line.split(":")
        if len(s) > 1:
            print s[1].strip()
```